# After an employee has sustained an injury, who should be making the Ramped Return To Work plan?

Tags: human-resources, united-kingdom

Given an injury which impacts an employee's ability to work ... followed by a period of extended sick leave, and now an extended Ramped Return to Work plan....

Should it be the employee who makes it, and presents it to the employer/HR to be approved?

Should it be the employer/HR who makes it and says "this is your plan, accept it or move on"?

Should it be an initial conversation to get views, followed by one side making the final plan (if so, which side should be doing the final making of the plan)

Should it be a fully collaborative process?

Are there differences between "What's common / reasonable?" and "What's legally required?" (if injury consideration is legally protected)

Comment: Obviously I know which option *I* think it should be (fully collab), but my employer is generally unusually collaborative in its general dealing with employees, so I have no handle on what the societal norms are.

Comment: I don't see any medical personnel mentioned.  Shouldn't your doctor have some input?

Comment: I would have assumed the Ramped Return to Work plan, would essentially be, the amount of time the doctor, indicates is the typical amount to until recovery.

Comment: I would have assumed it was the doctor who made the plan. They are the person with a medical license who understand how the human body works who can best advise the employee on what they should do to fully recover (as much as possible).

Answer (score 5):

In my experience this is worked out between you, your doctor, your manager, the HR department (who may have their own medical advisors on tap) your insurance and the company's insurance (both of whom definitely have doctors on tap though they may blindly apply policy instead).

It won't be fully collaborative; the parties have different and sometimes conflicting goals. It may be iterative but you won't see much if any of that process. You submit your doctor's recommendations to HR and the machine spins it's gears until you're told whether they accept your doctor's advice or want to do something different, then you and your manager work out how you can be most productive during that time without further hurting yourself.

In my case, the upshot was "we know you want to get back to work, we know you are still pretty washed out, work the hours you can and accomplish what you can." Which is what I needed; it was a full year before I was really fully functional again, but sitting in the office and trying was better for both me and the company than sitting at home and moping.

Answer (score 1):

> Should it be the employee who makes it,  ...
> Should it be the employer/HR who makes it

Neither. It should come from a medical professional. Neither employee or employer have the medical knowledge to create a credible ramp plan. This is also what most insurances and local law require (for that very reason).

> Should it be a fully collaborative process?

It should be **driven** by a medical professional with input from employee and the employer.

It also needs to be constantly monitored and **adjusted** as needed. Medical recovery is not highly predictable process, so specifying today what you will be may be able to do in 3 months from now is kind of silly.

In my experience this works fairly well in practice since there is  an "objective" party, which is the medical professional. It's also not necessarily a controversial situation: A successful well managed recovery is in everyone's best long-term interest. A company is unlikely to push for more aggressive ramp up against the advice of a doctor since (amongst other things) it creates a significant legal exposure risk for them.

A potential complication is when multiple doctors with conflicting opinions show up. That could get messy, but I have never see this actually happening.

Comment: The issue here is which of your private medical information should be available to your employer. This issue is usually resolved by you asking your doctor for recommendations which the doctor gives to you and you hand this to your employer, see keshlam's answer. Your doctor talking to company HR about your medical conditions is generally a big no-no.